# "Troubleshooting Data Insertion Discrepancies: Excel Upload via SqlBulkCopy on Localhost vs. IIS"

Tags: c#, sql-server, iis

When attempting to upload Excel data using SqlBulkCopy, the program functions correctly on localhost, successfully inserting data into the table. However, when running it on IIS, only the initial 30,000 records are inserted accurately, while subsequent records are inserted as null values. Despite having over 100,000 records.

```cs
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
 {
     sqlConnection.Open();

     using (SqlBulkCopy bulkInsert = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnection))
     {
         bulkInsert.DestinationTableName = "IA_student_Master";
         bulkInsert.BatchSize = 100; // Adjust batch size as needed

         // Add column mappings here
         bulkInsert.ColumnMappings.Add("COLLEGE_CODE", "college_code");
         bulkInsert.ColumnMappings.Add("REGNO", "usn_code");
         bulkInsert.ColumnMappings.Add("SNAME", "s_name");
         bulkInsert.ColumnMappings.Add("COURSE_CODE", "c_id");
         bulkInsert.ColumnMappings.Add("SUBJECT_CODE", "sub_code1");
         bulkInsert.ColumnMappings.Add("SUBJECT_NAME", "sub_name");

         bulkInsert.WriteToServer(excelDataReader);
     }

     // Show success message using JavaScript alert
     ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Data Uploaded Successfully!');", true);
 }
```

Comment: Can you show the excelDataReader setup also?

Comment: If you are using the ACEDB database provider: be aware that it's not supported in non-GUI (server or running as a service) environments and weird stuff might happen. You should consider using the OpenXML library to parse Excel files.

Comment: Maybe a timeout occurred, orthere's a network blip. Is the issue 100% reproducible?  Also, without an error message, you won't receive a useful answer.